# Thread safe copyable circular buffer in boost

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I'm using boost 1.53 and I'd like to have a thread safe implementation of circular buffer inside my app. Please have a look at the app concept below :

I have N sockets from where I read data and put it to the respective circular buffer. The point is that I don't know the exact number of sockets to be opened ( they could be opened even dynamically )
One obvious solution appeared in my mind is to have a map between  and  inside my class. But it's not possible to achieve as mutex is not a copyable object.

What is the best solution for my task? Any ideas would be appreciated.
Looking forward to your replies.

Tnx in advance,
Dmitry

Answer (score 1):

> But it's not possible to achieve as mutex is not a copyable object.

Which is not a problem, since you don't want the copy's mutex to have any relationship to the original's mutex.

You can just copy the *data* as you would for a normal map and then default construct a *new mutex* for the copy.

```
class MyBuffer
{
    std::map<key_T, value_T> m_data;
    mutable std::mutex m_mutex;
public:
    MyBuffer(MyBuffer const& other)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(other.m_mutex);
        m_data = other.m_data;
    }
    // [...]
};
```

Comment: So if I take bounded buffer implementation from here http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/circular_buffer/doc/circular_buffer.html#boundedbuffer and implement a copy constructor in a way you've posted, is that will be Ok?

Comment: Well, you still have wrap the access to the buffer accordingly so that you always properly lock when accessing the underlying buffer for reading or writing. But if you do this correctly you can just use the circular buffer from Boost.

Comment: The main problem for me - is that I can't use bounded buffer as it due to it's noncopial nature. Of course, I can implement these methods, but won't it break smth? Are their any side effects of doing this way?

Comment: @Dmitry I don't see your problem. Circular buffer is [perfectly copyable](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost/circular_buffer.html#idp20823160-bb).

Comment: "Circular buffer" yes, but I'm talking about "bounded buffer" class. And it's not copyable. Do you think it's no harm to implement copy-constructor for bounded-buffer class in a way you suggested?

Comment: @Dmitry That was supposed to be the point of my answer: Yes, you can implement a copy constructor for such a class in this way.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot for your help. You've really destroyed my fear for doing this as I'm not much experienced in boost.

Comment: `lock` is a non-`const` member function of `std::mutex`, so this will only work if `MyBuffer::m_mutex` is declared `mutable`.